# Is Google chrome and chromium are different browser

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have Ubuntu 12 in my PC. During installation of useful software, I was looking for browser except Firefox(which is by default browser). Through Ubuntu Software manager, I got Chromium and installed it. Its looks like Google Chrome. Is it the same as Google Chrome?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Chrome and Chromium are different products.

- Chromium is an fully open-source browser based on code from Google (and *many* other people, we shouldn't neglect to mention the engine is based on KHTML/Webkit)
- Chrome embodies much of Chromium but adds proprietary code (Flash player, licensed codecs, etc).

See: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome